# Allow duplicated column names in query result

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query:

```
WITH cte as (
SELECT 
    user.id, 
    user.name, 
    product.id as 'product_id', 
    product.price, 
    product.name as 'product_name',
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY user.id) AS dr
) select 
    user.id, 
    user.name, 
    product_id as 'id', 
    product.price, 
    product_name as 'name' 
from cte
WHERE dr between 1 and 3
ORDER BY id, product_id
```

returns this:

```
id;name;id;price;name;dr
1;Adam;16;500;book;1
2;Adam;51;600;guitar;1
3;Adam;16;100;mouse;1
4;Bob;32;300;car;2
5;Jan;77;2000;car;3
```

This columns structure is exactly what I need, because my `ORM` library expect that both `user` and `product` id columns are named: `id`. The way I archived that is I changed `id` to `product_id`, and changed to `id` in a second select. This looks weird to me - is there any easier way of doing that?

Comment: Why not use `product_id` in the second select?

Comment: That's perfectly normal. SELECT queries can have multiple columns with the same name. What's the problem?

Comment: As an aside, don't use single quotes for identifiers. T-SQL allows this in certain places, but it's ambiguous with string literals (which are sometimes allowed unquoted, to make things even more fun), so it can give very unexpected results. Always use either `[]` or `""` quoting syntax for identifiers only and `''` for strings only.

Comment: @StonedTensor my I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how complicated your query is, but here's another alternative using  `distinct top` with `order by` in the `where` clause. If you need to select a range of ids, you can modify that sub-query to use `offset` and `fetch`.

```
select * --rename columns however you want
from t1 join t2 on...
where t1.id in (select distinct top 3 id from t1 order by id)
```